Angular 17 SSR An image with src has intrinsic file dimensions
I'm new using Angular 17 and im trying to use some images charged in S3 Bucket in AWS, but it throws me the next warning
main.ts:6 NG0913: An image with src https://images.lowcostassist.com/home/desktop/image-seguro-de-objetos-personales_8_11zon.webp has intrinsic file dimensions much larger than its rendered size. This can negatively impact application loading performance. For more information about addressing or disabling this warning, see https://angular.io/errors/NG0913. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0913
I was trying to use the recommendation from Angular https://angular.io/errors/NG0913 but nothing works for me, someone could help me to fix that or if I have to change the images.
<img class="img-bnr" [srcset]="imgSrc" alt="" loading="eager">

getSrcImage(width: any) {
const display = width;
if (display > 1280) {
  this.imgSrc = 'https://images.lowcostassist.com/home/desktop/AdobeStock_297432602+1.webp';
} else if (display > 768) {
  this.imgSrc = 'https://images.lowcostassist.com/home/desktop/AdobeStock_297432602+3.webp';
} else {
  this.imgSrc = 'https://images.lowcostassist.com/home/mobile/AdobeStock_297432602+2.webp';
}

}

Hi, you need to make sure that the images you are using have dimensions that are close to or exactly the size they will be rendered at (more complicated). In a best case scenario, you will create different versions of your image for different screen sizes.

@AnwarMEQOR so, I have to change the sizes of the images ?

You should take a look at this optimization guide for images :
https://angular.dev/guide/image-optimization.
I also recommend you to dowload images in your project si you'll be more flexible and have more control on them
By the way, if you use server side rendering, the server side render won't be able to perform right choice of image because it is not aware of the client screen size.
